# C++ Builder 10.2 linker out of memory when using boost variant

Tags: c++, memory, boost, variant

I am using C++ Builder 10.2 (Rad Studio 10.2.3)
I had some issues and needed to use boost variant
Since I integrated boost variant, I can no longer link my application. I am always getting an "out of memory" error message, both for 32 bit and 64 bit platforms.

I tried the solution below:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Handling_Out_of_Memory_Errors.
But I am still having the same issue!

is there a real solution to that problem? A solution for 32 bit and 64 bit platforms will be appreciated. If not possible, 64 bit solution is the most important

Comment: Try a different compiler? Also, without the code you're unlikely to get help.

Comment: ¿How much RAM do you have and which boost version are you using?

Comment: I have boost 1.55 installed.
I have 8GB RAM on my computer. For the RAM available it varies between 2.5 and 3.5 GB depending on programs which are running. I tried close all programs and keep only Rad Studio but it did not solve the issue.